# Connectivity checking in Google App Engine using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine

I have deployed my index.php file on Google App Engine. When I opened my file using `gcloud app deploy` command it's opening in my browser and displaying the echo statement I have written in the `index.php` file.

Now I want to check whether my data base is connecting or not using another PHP file:

dbconnect.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect(null, "user", "user123", "test","0","/cloudsql/mycloudinstance");

if (!$conn) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}else{

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($conn) . PHP_EOL;


}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

My `app.yaml` file:

```
runtime: php72
handlers:

- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

I do not know how to run my dbconnect.php file. Also tried to add dbconnect.php in script tag. But it is giving error.

Comment: Could you please share the errors in logs? In addition, just to clarify, are you trying to connect to CloudSQL MySQL?

Comment: I want to run the php file. I do not not know how to do that..

Comment: Then you can copy and paste all content in it on index.php in order to verify your connection with the DB

Comment: I found a solution by keeping the URLs in app.yaml..